# How to re-set what happens when I connect my Galaxy to the USB?

Tags: windows-8, usb

I'm tired of Explorer showing up the contents of my phone storage every time I connect it for charging. It seemed like a good idea at the moment but it's become quite annoying now. I tried to change what's going to happen when the device is connected. I can't find the setting.

The only method I can think of at the moment is to remove the device from found ones and re-discover it again. Not smooth, precisely...

How do people do that?!

Comment: which galaxy and which android version?

Comment: Does it matter? I need Win8 to react on me connecting an USB device to the computer in a different way then now (do-nothing instead of open-for-browsing). Anyway, it's G3 and the latest update.

Comment: On my Android phone I can set my USB prefs to Charge Only or Mount Data. If its set to charge only, the comp doesn't recognize it as a usb device. That's why I asked what model and version.

Comment: Oh, you mean like that... I didn't even know there was such an option in Android. Cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control Panel>All Items>AutoPlay

scroll down to the bottom to choose for a specific device.

[image]